# How to determine which properties of a RESTful resource have changed before save when using Spring Data REST repositories?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

If I have the following resource published by Spring Data REST...

`{ "status": "idle" }`

How could I react to a PATCH or PUT that changes the value of property `status`? The idea would be to trigger some server process based on a property change.

Ideally this would happen before save and it would be possible to compare the new version of the resource with the previously-persisted version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would usually use a `@RepositoryEventHandler` to hook up your event logic - see the [documentation for details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler).

I do not know of a function to directly get the changed properties. But if you use a `HandleBeforeSave` handler you can load the persistent entity (old state) and compare it against the new state -

```
    @RepositoryEventHandler 
    @Component
    public class PersonEventHandler {

      ...

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;

      @HandleBeforeSave
      public void handlePersonSave(Person newPerson) {
        entityManager.detach(newPerson);
Person currentPerson = personRepository.findOne(newPerson.getId());
        if (!newPerson.getName().equals(currentPerson.getName)) {
          //react on name change
        }
       }
    }
```

Note that you need to detach the newPerson from the current EntityManager. Otherwise we would get the cached person object when calling findOne - and we could not compare to the updated version against the current database state.

**Alternative if using Eclipselink**

If you are using eclipselink you can also find out the changes that have been applied to your entity in a more efficient fashion avoiding the reload - see [here for details](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_access_what_changed_in_an_object_or_transaction.3F)

```
        UnitOfWorkChangeSet changes = entityManager.unwrap(UnitOfWork.class).getCurrentChanges();
        ObjectChangeSet objectChanges = changes.getObjectChangeSetForClone(newPerson);
        List<String> changedAttributeNames = objectChanges.getChangedAttributeNames();
        if (objectChanges.hasChangeFor("name")) {
            ChangeRecord changeRecordForName = objectChanges.getChangesForAttributeNamed("name");
            String oldValue = changeRecordForName.getOldValue();

        }
```

Comment: This does not work. newPerson and currentPerson end up being the same instance of Person in your example. I'm not able to get the "currentPerson" that exists in the database. It's as if Spring Data Rest has already attached newPerson to the JPA session, so the later query gets the new value.

Comment: If I inject EntityManager into PersonEventHandler annotated with @PersistenceContext, and do entityManager.detach(newPerson) before the currentPerson query, this works as expected. I'll accept your answer if you update your code to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielBauman for the hint - your are absolutely right - our finder would not go to the database but returns the person object already registered in the EntityManager - to be able to compare against the current state we need to detach the object before. I updated my answer accordingly.